Why should I keep an ASUS-BE device away from 802.11g or 20MHz only Wi-Fi devices?
I read this in the manual of ASUS-BE: "Keep the device away from 802.11g or 20MHz only Wi-Fi devices".
I was wondering what's so special about 802.11g or 20MHz only Wi-Fi devices? Are they some much different from 802.11a/b/n or 40/80/160MHz devices?


@Gantendo My question is, why single out 802.11g and 20MHz? Why is the interference they introduced stronger than the other standards/channel width? Of course they will interfere with the router, so do 802.11 a/b/n/ac/ax/be and all other channel widths.

802.11g operates at 2.4 GHz.  If you have other devices running at the same frequency and channel you will cause inference. 2.412 GHz + 20 MHz would encompass all channels supported by 802.11g (CH 5-7) overlaps all 11 channels. 802.11g has not mitigation to that problem.

@Ramhound Sorry I'm not sure I followed the CH 5-7 part. Shouldn't routers use 1,6,11 to mitigate adjacent channel interferences? I just don't know why it's an 802.11 g-specific problem. Isn't it the case for 802.11n as well?

802.11g is ONLY 2.4 GHz. 802.11n has 20 Mhz and 40 Mhz channels.

Since the transmission power (TX power) of a device does not change as the channel width increases, 20MHz-only devices will have the strongest signal compared to 40/80/160/320MHz devices.
Also, devices that only support 20MHz may incur OBSS interference, as prior to 802.11ac, secondary channels do not have a mechanism to detect existing signals at its frequency.

Source of the image.
